# PerformancePoint Designer White space / Blank Space

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I've searched quite a bit for this but I can't find a solution. I'm creating an Analytic Chart in the PerformancePoint dashboard designer to eventually push up for SharePoint 2013.

When in the "Design" tab creating the chart, there's a bunch of white space / blank space to the left of the chart. The right side of the chart is cut off and if I put the legend over there, I can't see it. The extra space seems to be carrying over into web parts when putting up in SharePoint in certain scenarios.

A contractor created a chart for us 6 months ago and it's completely left aligned in the designer. If I recreate the exact chart exactly with the same data source/ fields, it doesn't left align like his did.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the custom theme/styling we had created for our SharePoint site by an external consulting company. I can't speak to what exactly the issue was but if anyone has this issue, you can start with any custom themes/styles.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I figured 98% of an answer was better than no answer